# get a set of joined instances from a table using Criteria API

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria-api

I have an entity `PrintingFare`
and a foreign key there  -  `Printer`, 
so how do I use Criteria API that way so I get a set of Printers, which have Printing fares?

Basically I have a class `PrintingFare` with this field

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "printer_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_fares_ref_printer_id"))
private Printer printer;
```

How do I get a set of Printers using Criteria API?

Answer (score 1):

You should add restrictions to the query

```
  Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(PrintingFare.class);
  criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("printer.id", printerId));
  List<PrintingFare> list = criteria.list();

  Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Printer.class);
  criteria.createAlias("printerFairs", "pf").add(Restrictions.in("pf.id", printerFairIds));
  List<Printer> list = criteria.list();
```

Comment: This gives you a list of printing fares for a given printer. I think the OP wanted a list of printers that have one or more printing fares associated with it.

Comment: @JoãoMendes It's easily done if you have associated list of printing fairs. Feel free to post a solution ;)

Comment: yes but can this been done with just a criteria query?

Comment: @nikpon  I'd rather do it with just criteria, without looping through result

Comment: @tania try the second query, not sure if it needs a fetch mode

Comment: @nikpon but where i get printerFairIds from?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but you can try:

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(PrintingFare.class);
criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("printer"));
List<Printer> list = criteria.list();
```

Let me know if it works. It will probably have to be tweaked.

Answer (score 0):

If PrinterFares is mapped from the Printer.class side ...

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Printer.class);
criteria.createAlias("printerFares", "pf");
criteria.add(Restrictions.isNotEmpty("pf"));
crit.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

List<Printer> printers = criteria.list();
```

If you are unable to change the mapping of Printer.class ...

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Printer.class);
// create a subquery
DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(PrinterFare.class);
dc.setProjection(Projections.property("printer.id"));
// restrict by subquery
criteria.add(Subqueries.in("id", dc);
crit.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

List<Printer> printers = criteria.list();
```